# Spring MVC 3 Time scheduled task starting at a specific time

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to schedule a method call in Spring MVC to run after every two hours. This I can easily do via Spring 3.0 Time Scheduler. However, I want to kick the execution off only at a specific time of the day. That is, the method should only be invoked every 2 hours starting at a particular time.

For example - I want the method to run every 2 hours starting  6 AM.
The TimeScheduler interface has a scheduleAtFixedRate method which is overloaded to use startTime Date argument. I am not really sure how to use this.

Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at the `TaskScheduler` interface.  It provides a method `scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period)` which returns a `ScheduledFuture`.  You can use this with some simple Spring configuration:

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

This will create an instance of `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` which implements `TaskScheduler`.  Wire this bad boy into the class to call your specific method:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    public void init() {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myMethod();
            }
        }, new Date(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2); //This will start now and run every two hours
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        // the method you want to invoke
    }
}
```

Comment: Well both the approaches are right, depends on what approach you want to follow.I chose the cron eventually. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Spring's support for [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).  Specifically check out the `@Scheduled` annotation (with which you can specify a schedule based on a cron expression):

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute on weekdays only
}
```

Comment: I did try that, what I could not achieve is triggering the repeated execution at a specific time of the day.

Comment: Repeated for how long?  Is this something you want to happen everyday, or just start one day and run forever?

Comment: I want this to start at a particular time of the day (this is done once) and thereafter execution happens every 2 hours forever.